# MC9S08QD4 - assigning to doubles/longs "corrupts" unrelated variables

Tags: c, memory, microcontroller

### Overview

I'm trying to program a frequency divider using a MC9S08QD4 microcontroller. It uses an 8-bit architecture following the HCS08 instruction set ([documentation available here](http://www.physics.mcmaster.ca/phy4d6/MCU/MC9S08/HCS08%20Instruction%20Set%20Summary.pdf)).

However, in order to accommodate input frequencies in as wide a range as possible, I've been trying to use `double` and `unsigned long` variables for storing properties such as the period of the input signal.

The issue I'm having is this: whenever I assign values to `double` or `long` variables, it *correctly* assigns the value to that variable but *also* overwrites completely unrelated parts of memory, corrupting other variables that may be stored there. A colleague suggested that this might be because it's using those locations to store intermediate values during calculation, which would be very odd if it's the case.

### Environment

These are the tools I'm working with as a reference for the remainder of this post:

- Windows 7 64-bit development machine
- CodeWarrior Development Studio 10.7

### Details

In certain parts of my code I assign potentially large values to `long` or `double` variables. By "large" I mean greater than what a 16-bit value could support but well within the range of what an unsigned 32-bit integer or double could support.

If I inspect local/global variables while performing these assignments, I can see that the variable I'm assigning to is assigned as expected, but so are other variables. I can also inspect the memory as I do this, where I see arbitrary and disparate locations being overwritten when I assign to these variables.

By following [this guide](https://mcuoneclipse.com/2013/05/08/addingremoving-floating-point-format-for-s08-projects/), I've taken all the steps I'm aware of to ensure support for working with large/potentially floating data types:

- Set the S08 linker to include `ansis.lib`, which uses `small HCS08` memory model and supports 32-bit floats and 64-bit doubles.
- Ensured `__NO_FLOAT__` is **not** defined as a preprocessor symbol.
- Ensured `Use IEEE32 for double (default is IEEE64)` in HCS08 Compiler settings is **not** selected (although for my use case 32-bit doubles is fine).
- Ensured all data types are the expected sizes under `HCS08 Compiler -> Type Sizes`.

I've also verified that variables are being allocated the correct amount of memory in the generated map file and from the variable debugging screen.

**SSCCE**

I've been able to reproduce this issue easily with a very small amount of code in a dummy project I've set up:

```
static double temp = 0;
static double temp2 = 0;
static double temp3 = 0;

void main(void)
{
    double a = 1000;
    double b = a + 2;

    temp = 1;
    temp2 = temp + 2;
    temp3 = temp2 + 3;
}
```

Immediately after flashing the board, my IDE looks like this:

[image]

So far so good. The global variables are initialised to 0, and the local variables have indeterminate values which is fine as they haven't been assigned to yet. Progressing past the first line, I see that `a` has been assigned correctly with no issues:

[image]

Stepping one more line, I find that the assignment to `b` succeeded but corrupted my global variables:

[image]

[image]

**Disassembly**

Below is the disassembly for the first two lines of code in `main`. I've linked the HCS08 instruction set in **Overview**.

```
 5    void main(void)
f092:   A7F0 AIS #-16
 7      double a = 1000;
f094:   5F CLRX
f095:   8C CLRH
f096:   9EFF07 STHX 7,SP
f099:   9EFF05 STHX 5,SP
f09c:   454000 LDHX #0x4000
f09f:   9EFF03 STHX 3,SP
f0a2:   AE8F LDX #0x8F
f0a4:   9EFF01 STHX 1,SP
 8      double b = a + 2;
f0a7:   95 TSX
f0a8:   CDF4F1 JSR 0xF4F1 _DADD_RC (0xf4f1)
f0ab:   40 NEGA
f0ac:   000000 BRSET 0,0x00,*+3 main+0x15 (0xf0af)
f0af:   000000 BRSET 0,0x00,*+3 main+0x15 (0xf0b2)
f0b2:   00AF08 BRSET 0,0xAF,*+11 main+0x26 (0xf0bd)
f0b5:   CDF13A JSR 0xF13A _POP64 (0xf13a)
```

The instructions for `double a = 1000;` look reasonable, but those for `double b = a + 2;` involve a jump that leads down a *very deep* rabbit hole that I've not been able to return from.

Any advice about why this might be happening would be appreciated.

**Edit**

I've uploaded the memory map file for my real project [here](http://pastebin.com/sm6dsQf8) (not enough space left in this post to include it directly). This is in response to those suggesting this is a matter of limited memory, which I don't believe is correct.

Comment: One possible theory: The optimizer sees that temp1, temp2, and temp3 aren't being read, and in fact are about to be assigned, and therefore uses them for temporary storage as an optimization. Probably because emulating doubles is expansive. It must still adhere to the as-if rule, however, so at the end of main all variables must hold the expected values. Do they hold the expected values?

Comment: This is a very well-written question. :) The screenshots are a bit hard to read for my aging eyes, but the ambition is admirable. Just wanted to point that out, since it's a bit rare.

Comment: I must say this is the first time I've seen 8-bit controller use a 64-bit float. :) But nevertheless, I would presume an optimizing compiler would actually ignore the temporary `double` variables and move on to dealing with statics - although since `double` are not intrinsic to the compiler it probably cannot know if adding `_DADD_RC` causes side effects, so it must call it anyway. Not related to your question, but I am sure using fixed point arithmetics would be much more performant and would probably avoid many of the issues with floats.

Comment: @StoryTeller I think you're onto something - not sure how I hadn't noticed before but if I run it all the way through I find that `temp2` and `temp3` "magically" acquire the correct values by the end (even though `temp` still appears to corrupted, but behind the scenes is probably also alright). http://i.imgur.com/XhlRiR4.png

Comment: So follow up to this - do you know how I could disable this optimisation? 256 bytes of RAM isn't much but I'm sure the compiler could find somewhere else to store these intermediate values. Looking at the variables is pretty much the only tool available to stop the whole system being a black box to me while running.

Comment: @unwind Sorry about the screenshots, shame it doesn't expand them when you hover-over. :)

Comment: Tagc, I think the more impotent question is "why is this a problem"? I'd wager that you have a variable used as part of an expression with unspecified or undefined evaluation order. As such the compiler is free to produce even incorrect code. Try to fix that expression, and enjoy the optimizations.

Comment: @Tagc: even if the statics get corrupted, it's rather logical they will end up having correct values if you overwrite them. **But `temp` doesn't seem to hold number `1` at the end, if I am correct?** Also, try moving the temporary double addition *after* the static `temp` calculation and see if they get corrupted. It's quite possible the compiler doesn't care about those statics until the first time they are accessed, especially since you're limited with memory.

Comment: @Groo Not sure what you mean. Do you mean like this? http://i.imgur.com/ixbQmuW.png In which case it flags those last two lines as being removed as dead assignments. You're right that `temp` doesn't seem to hold 1 at the end.

Comment: Assuming you are using the messed up Eclipse version of CW, go Project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Optimizations -> Disable optimization (-O0). Failing that, declare the variables as volatile.

Comment: @Tagc: Yes, that's what I meant. In essence, you want to see if the compiler will "allow" static variables to be messed up after working with them. But since `temp` seems to be corrupted at the end, I don't think this is valid compiler behavior anyway.

Comment: @Groo - I disagree. `temp` isn't read after being written. By the as-if rule, there's no harm in reusing it until the end of the scope.

Comment: @StoryTeller: despite it's poorly chosen name, `temp` is *not* a local variable, and its scope doesn't end anywhere inside the `main` function. You could by this logic say exactly the same about `temp2`, `temp3`, even more so regarding the `a` and `b` variables, or argue that the compiler can do *anything* here, since there is no observable behavior unless you attach a debugger. IMHO, if a compiler chooses *not* to optimize `a` and `b` (which have a limited scope without any side effects), and then feels free to corrupt a static field at the end, replace the compiler.

Comment: @Groo I'm applying this logic because the *entire program* ends. It's not impossible or even too difficult for an optimzer to deduce that variable is unused after being written. The as-if rule still holds. And yes, the optimizer is free to choose *any* unused variable as a scratch variable.

Comment: @StoryTeller: 1) *"unused after being written"* - it's used after being written, right in the next line, 2) *"variable is unused"* - it's not a variable, it's a field which lives for the entire duration of the program. 3) *"the as-if rule still holds"* - `temp` doesn't contain `1` at the end of the program, so I am really not sure what the "as-if rule" means for you.

Comment: @Groo 1) But not in the very next-next line 2) That soon ends after assigning to temp3 3) The as-if rule applies to observable behavior, for me and for most I'd think. If scrapping the entire program is acceptable (as it is here) then choosing temp as scratch space for computing temp3 is also perfectly fine. The value of temp is observable only when assigning to temp2, in this context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is most likely a stack overflow. The HCS08QD4 is not a PC, it is a very low-end 8-bit MCU with 256 bytes of RAM (including S08 "zero-page") and no FPU. Out of those 256 bytes, a small portion will be reserved for the stack per default. 80 bytes or so perhaps? To know exactly how much, check your linker file (.prm).

Most likely the floating-point library alone needs more RAM than you even have available on-chip.

As someone with some 15 years of experience of these parts, as well as the Codewarrior compiler, I'll be brutally honest: to pick such a limited MCU for a project that needs double precision floating point and 32-bit integer arithmetic is just sheer nonsense. Either you specified a completely wrong MCU for the task, or you are some kind of PC programmer just now switching over to embedded systems. Either way, there is no way you can ever get this program to work.

Start over the project from scratch, beginning with the specification.

Comment: I've worked with other MCUs for years (specifically LPC1788, less limited). I didn't pick the MCU - my boss did, gave it to me and told me to program this. I don't think your answer is correct judging from my memory map file (I'll edit it into my original post), and also given the fact that same issue is present in my extremely simple SSCCE which is about 10 lines long.

Comment: Also, I don't think I need doubles either, and I've dropped them in my real project. I definitely do need 32-bit integer support though, and the issue persists with them. As someone else suggested in the comments, this appears to just be an optimisation the compiler is using - the program might actually be working correctly but only appearing to incorrect while debugging (will test this next).

Comment: @Tagc `CDF4F1 JSR 0xF4F1 _DADD_RC (0xf4f1)` Here you are going to end up with multiple functions calls into the floating point library. Codewarrior will let you step through the library code and you can step on assembly instruction level. Simply watch the SP and see where it runs off into the woods. Not that it matters where, because you won't be able to make a meaningful program anyway with this little RAM. _Why_ exactly do you need to use floating point numbers?

Comment: As I said, I briefly tried using doubles and then changed all my `double` variables to `unsigned long`. I wanted floating point support because I needed to be able to scale the frequency of input signals by any positive real number. I've changed it though so my code works with an integer numerator and integer denominator instead. Between these changes, I've eliminated the need for floating point support.

Comment: Good idea about monitoring the SP register by the way - as I'm running through the (revised - floating point-free) code, the highest value that I observe is 0x138. According to the map file it can go up to 0x13D but it's certainly cutting it close.

Comment: @Tagc No wonder, since HCS08, like most CPUs, uses a _down-counting stack_...  You should watch for _low_ values close to 0x10E.

Comment: @Tagc: note the `AIS #-16` instruction at the beginning of the assembly. It's clearly down-counting.

Comment: @Groo Thanks, haven't dealt with this stuff since university. I understand that `AIS #-16` is decrementing the stack pointer by 16. If the stack is down-counting, this means it's reserving/allocating spaces for 16 bytes of data right? Am I correct to assume this would be things like the return value for main, the frame pointer, etc.? And yep, Lundin was right - [looks like I have a stack overflow](http://i.imgur.com/mbxgCaV.png).

Comment: By bumping the prescale value for the timers I use to max, I think I can get away with using 16-bit arithmetic at the cost of a little resolution (shouldn't matter much). I'll upvote this answer now and mark this answer as accepted later on when I've got a working solution and can confirm this was the primary issue.

Comment: @Tagc Indeed it reserves space for 16 bytes, perhaps suggesting that `double` is still 64 bit despite your configuration. There's no such thing as stack frames on the HCS08, it just stacks the return address (program counter) upon calling a function. The programmer/compiler is responsible for stacking accumulators. There should be no return value from main(). Your reset ISR will call main() and never expect it to return - this code is generated by Codewarrior by default.

Comment: Although you can certainly do 64-bit (or any-bit) math with 8-bit MCUs (I do it all the time with 9S08 MCUs), the QD4 in particular is rather limited memory-wise, and my advice is to NOT program it in C -- except for trivial applications.  Use assembly language instead, or get a bigger memory chip.  BTW, floating point is rarely truly needed -- use lower overhead integer math and save about half your 4KB program storage. 48 bytes of stack is hopeless even with interrupts disabled.  Look, to put it simply: you can't carry an elephant with a Smart!

Comment: Rewrote my program to use only 16-bit arithmetic. Seems to be working okay and SP stays within the comfy 0x120/0x130 range.